# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-2:sonar

Tags: plugins, maven-2, jenkins, sonarqube

We're using Sonar with jobs started by Jenkins.
Now we get this error when Jekins
tries to run sonar-maven-plugin:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-2:sonar (default-cli) on project SS_MGWTDMWebUI: Can not execute Sonar: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.start()', instance 'org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverDatabaseConnector@1a791f, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper: Cannot open connection to database: SQL driver not found com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Are you using the [Jenkins Sonar plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin) or are you invoking Sonar directly? Do you have anything unusual in your `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` files?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states "SQL driver not found com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".
Assuming your install is OK, can you check sonar.host.url does not end with '/' ?

see [sonar-1685](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1685)